# Finding max of difference + element for an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have an array consisting of each entry as a tuple of two integers. Let the array be `A = [(a1, b1), (a2, b2), .... , (an, bn)]`. Now we have multiple queries where we are given an integer `x`, we need to find the maximum value of `ai + |x - bi| for 1 <= i <= n`.

I understand this can be easily achieved in `O(n)` time complexity for each query but I am looking for something faster than that, probably `O(log n)` for each query. I can preprocess the array in `O(n)` time, but the queries should be done faster than `O(n)`.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to see the problem from the other side: for the given set of pairs, the pairs with `ai + |x - bi|` larger than all others for `x` larger than any `bi` are those with maximum `ai - bi`. What is the next smaller region?

Comment: @greybeard So there are two possible cases. `x > bi` and `x < bi`. For the first case I need to find out the maximum of `ai - bi` and for the latter `ai + bi`. And then I can compare them by adding x to the first one and subtracting x from the last one and then answering the one which comes maximum between those two.

Comment: @greybeard also what I can do to preprocess is sort the array by b so that given x we can find the border for x quickly by binary search and then keep segment trees with the aforementioned values to find the maximum of those two segments in sublinear time. I think that should work.

Comment: I'm inclined to process the *(ai, bi)* in order of decreasing *ai*: if *|bj - bi|* < *ai - aj*, *(ai, bi)* "dominates" *(aj, bj)*: for no value of x, *aj + |x - bj|* will be larger than *ai + |x - bi|*

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be way too easy to over-think this.
For `n = 1`, the function is v-shaped with a minimum of `a1` at `b1`, with slopes of -1 and 1, respectively - let's call these values `ac` and `bc` (for *combined*).
For an additional pair `(ai, bi)`, one of the pairs may *dominate* the other (`|bc - bi| ≤ |ac - ai`), which may then be ignored.
Otherwise, the falling slope of the combination will be from the pair with the larger `b`, the rising slope from the other.
The minimum will be between the individual `b`, closer to the `b` of the pair with the larger `a`, the distance being half the difference between the (absolute value of the) "coordinate" differences, the minimum value that amount higher.
The main catch is that neither needs to be an integer - the only alternative being *exactly in the middle between two integers*.
(Ending up with the falling slope from max `ai + bi`, and the rising slope of max `ai - bi`.)